# Android MaterialAutoCompleteTextView hide Keyboard on show ExposedDropdownMenu

Tags: android, keyboard, hide

Consider a MaterialAutoCompleteTextView nested in a TextInputLayout using an ExposedDowpdownMenu. How do I hide a Softkeyboard already shown by a previous TextInputEditText? It also should hide the keyboard if we navigate from the previous focused TextInputEditText with an imeOption=actionNext. Since the MaterialAutoCompleteTextView decorated with an ExposedDropdownMenu is not focusable onFocusChanged() does not work. Additionally, I didn't found any property like i.e. "onShowDropDown" or similar to trigger my "hideKeyboard()" method.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".75"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/cvinfo_city"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/cvinfo_city"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@={viewModel.user.general.address.city}" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/cvinfo_country"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/cvinfo_country"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@{viewModel.user.general.address.country}" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: imeAction=next keyboard does not hide]

imeAction=next keyboard does not hide

[image: Also want to hide keyboard if dropdown shows]

Also want to hide keyboard if dropdown shows

Answer (score 2):

Adding an OnFocusChangeListener to hide the keyboard when the dropdown gets the focus worked for me:

```
dropdown.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            view.context.getSystemService(InputMethodManager::class.java).hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code

```
//Step1: Add in the root of the layout
android:clickable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 

//Step2: Add this method
public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
  InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

//Step3: Add this setOnFocusChangeListener event in onStart for the editText
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
  if (!hasFocus) {
        hideKeyboard(v);
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: one mistake hasFocus

Answer (score 0):

To not show the keyboard when opening the dropdown add the following to in your XML code:

```
android:inputType="none"
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but if it is already shown, android:inputType="none" does nothing. The Keyboard is still on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Kotlin version.

In layout

```
      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
                style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
                android:labelFor="@id/menu_autocomplete">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/menu_autocomplete"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
```

on onCreate()

```
menuAutocomplete.setOnTouchListener { _, ev->
            if (ev.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                hideKeyboard(this)
                menuButton.performClick()
            }
            return@setOnTouchListener false
        }
        menuButton.setOnTouchListener { _, ev ->
            if (ev.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                hideKeyboard(this)
            return@setOnTouchListener false
        }
```

Where Button is:

```
private val menuButton by lazy {
    binding.menuLayout.findViewById<CheckableImageButton>(com.google.android.material.R.id.text_input_end_icon)
}
```

And hideKeyboard() is:

```
fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity)
{
    val imm = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.currentFocus?.windowToken, 0)
}
```